# I'm trying to import Open Data Kit Sc that i got from github, but i kept getting error (I'm new to android)

Tags: android, import

This is my build.gradle

```
if ((new File(gradle.local)).exists()) {
    apply from: gradle.local
} else {
    apply from: gradle.remote
}

applicationScripts.each {
    apply from: it
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
// The following are set in the common.gradle file
compileSdkVersion("Google Inc.:Google APIs:19")
buildToolsVersion("22.0.1")

defaultConfig {
    applicationId("org.odk.collect.android")
    minSdkVersion(8)
    targetSdkVersion(8)
    versionCode(1057)
    versionName("1.4.8")
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled(minify)
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),        'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
    snapshot {
        // Build type for snapshots
    }
    debug {
        testCoverageEnabled(testCoverage) // Allows AndroidTest JaCoCo reports to be generated
    }
}

packagingOptions { // Pick first occurrence of any files that cause conflicts, as defined in common.gradle
    packageList.each {
        pickFirst it
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
if (playServicesPath.exists() && gradle.useLocal) { // Local project is    favoured
    compile project(playServicesName)
} else {
    releaseCompile(group: groupId, name: playServicesArtifactName, version:   playServicesRelease, ext: 'aar')
    snapshotCompile(group: groupId, name: playServicesArtifactName, version:  playServicesSnapshot, ext: 'aar')
    debugCompile(group: groupId, name: playServicesArtifactName, version: playServicesSnapshot, ext: 'aar')
    }
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

The error i got is 
    Error:(12, 0) CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file     specified
Open File

I've tried all from importing all of the packages, importing only the folder that got the android manifest only, and i've tried to just open it, but it wont open.

Comment: this the link of the project, https://github.com/opendatakit/collect

Comment: Show the error messages.

Comment: he error i got is Error:(12, 0) CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified Open File

Answer (score 0):

Case Closed!

It turned out to be that i didn't follow the instruction well. Just try to pull it via git from github and it will be perfect.